# Are there any unstackable items that output 1 signal strength unit when attached to a comparator?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am Building a simple counter in minecraft with redstone, and I was wondering if there is a non-stackable item that outputs 1 signal strength while inside a dropper so I can get a comparator output and hook it up to redstone lamps.

I understand comparators and how they work and I use them all the time in my builds. My problem is I can’t seem to find a non-stackable item that only outputs a signal strength of 1 instead of 2 (I tried all the weapons/armor and potions and empty bottles....no luck)

Comment: All non-stackable items output the same signal strength, because the signal strength will be calculated by slots used.. (`<amount of items> / <max stack size>`)

Comment: Ah, ok I did not know that. I will just use snowballs then

Comment: @dly Can you please write that as an answer so that this question doesn't remain unanswered?

Answer (score 1):

There are no non-stackable items that only produce 1 comparator output. This is due to the way that comparators detect items in an inventory.

Comparators work in a different way than you think, they output a signal depending on how full the inventory is. All non-stackable items will make the hopper more full, (`5x1=5`) making the hopper only need 5 items to be full.  If you were to use something that stacks to 64, (`5x64=320`) you would need 320 items to fill the hopper.

If you would like something that gives only a 1 strength signal, use any stackable item instead.